# Postion of Robotic Arm Joints

Tags: robotic-arm

For the shown general serial link n-DOF robotic arm the joint inertial positions are given by $p_i$, where $i=1,...n$:

[image]

I learned that the joints' inertial positions can be calculated in one of two ways:

1- $p_i=r_o + b_o + \sum _{k=1}^{i} (a_k+b_k)$

2- As the first three elements of $\bar{p}_i$, where:
  $\bar{p}_i=T_o$ $^oT_1\text{...}$ $^{i-1}T_i$ $\bar{p}_0,$ $^{i-1}T_i$ is the homogeneous transformation matrix from coordinate $(i)$ to coordinate $(i-1)$, and $\bar{p}_0=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right). [1]$

By definition, the two methods should yield identical results. The problem is that they don't for a $\textbf{ wrist-partitioned manipultor}$.

$\textbf{My question is: Where could I be going wrong?}$

In the following I describe the specifics of my calculations:

1- $a_i$ is calculated as $a_i=A_o$ $^oA_1 ...$ $^{i-1}A_i$  $^ia_i$ (where $^{i-1}A_i$ is the rotation matrix). $b_i$ is calculated in a similar manner.

2- The homogeneous transformation matrix is

$^{i-1}T_i=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \cos \left(\theta _i\right) & -\sin \left(\theta _i\right) & 0 & a_i \\
 \cos \left(\alpha _i\right) \sin \left(\theta _i\right) & \cos \left(\alpha _i\right) \cos \left(\theta _i\right) & -\sin \left(\alpha _i\right) & -d_i \sin \left(\alpha _i\right) \\
 \sin \left(\alpha _i\right) \sin \left(\theta _i\right) & \sin \left(\alpha _i\right) \cos \left(\theta _i\right) & \cos \left(\alpha _i\right) & d_i \cos \left(\alpha _i\right) \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Where the rotation matrix,$^{i-1}A_i$, is the $3\times{3}$ top-left matrix. And $T_o$ is given by:

$T_o=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 A_o & r_o \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Where:

$A_o=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos \left(\theta _{b_z}\right) & -\sin \left(\theta _{b_z}\right) & 0 \\
 \sin \left(\theta _{b_z}\right) & \cos \left(\theta _{b_z}\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos \left(\theta _{b_y}\right) & 0 & \sin \left(\theta _{b_y}\right) \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -\sin \left(\theta _{b_y}\right) & 0 & \cos \left(\theta _{b_y}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos \left(\theta _{b_x}\right) & -\sin \left(\theta _{b_x}\right) \\
 0 & \sin \left(\theta _{b_x}\right) & \cos \left(\theta _{b_x}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

represents the rotation of the base. For fixed base systems $A_o$ and $T_o$ are identity matrices.

$\underline{EDIT}$:

My robot model and the DH parameters I obtained for it are shown below:

[image]

$ \alpha =[0^{\circ},90^{\circ},0^{\circ},-90^{\circ},0^{\circ},-90^{\circ}] \\
a=[0,0,a_2,0,0,0] \\
d=[d_1,d_2,0,d_4,0,0] \\
\theta =[\theta_1(t),\theta_2(t),\theta_3(t),\theta_4(t),\theta_5(t),\theta_6(t)] \\$
$\text{Where:} \\
$ 
$d_2=L_2 \\
d_1=L_1 \\
a_2=L_3 \\
d_4=L_5 $

$[1]$ Liu Haitao, Zhang Tie, "A New Approach to Avoid Singularities of
6-DOF Industrial Robot"

Comment: The equations look fine, it's likely to be a problem with your DH formulation. Can you add info on how you are choosing your DH parameters?

Comment: @hauptmech I made some edits.

Comment: @hauptmech If you can help me verify my DH parameters I'd be extremely grateful as my graduation project depends on it.

Answer (score 2):

Between frame 2 and 3, there should be a net 180° rotation about the Z axis. However, your second and third DH parameter seem to only have a net rotation of 90°.

Answer (score 0):

No valid dh parameters are possible for the transform from frame 1 to 2.  Try using a different configuration of the robot to find your DH parameters. Or don't use DH parameters.

Also remember that a constant offset in theta is one of the dh parameters if you care about where your joint zero is. $\theta = [\theta_{1DH}+\theta_{1}(t), ...]$